# How to prevent multiple selection in nattable?

Tags: nattable

I want the rows of nattable to be single-select only.

Now, multi-selection is possible using ctrl or shift. How do I make single-selection possible?

I would be very grateful if you could leave an answer to a question

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to support row selection only, you need to configure the `RowSelectionModel` to set the multipleSelectionAllowed flag to `false` and set it as SelectionModel to the SelectionLayer.

Have a look at our examples application to get an idea how this can be done.

Comment: Thanks for the reply

I've already implemented a function to select only rows, but I'd like to know how to do a single select here.

Can you give me an example name to refer to this? 
Or is it possible to do a single select function in the same way as a function to select only rows?

Comment: The `SelectionModel` provides the same feature. Have a look at the sources to get an idea what is supported.